# Python / Scipy filter discretization

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am currently trying to move from Matlab to Python and succeeded in several aspects. However, one function in Matlab's Signal Processing Toolbox that I use quite regularly is the [impinvar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/impinvar.html) function to calculate a digital filter from its analogue version.

In [Scipy.signal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/signal.html) I only found the [bilinear](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bilinear.html) function to do something similar. But, in contrast to the [Matlab bilinear function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bilinear.html), it does not take an optional argument to do some pre-warping of the frequencies. I did not find any impinvar (impulse invariance) function in Scipy.

Before I now start to code it myself I'd like to ask whether there is something that I simply overlooked? Thanks.

Comment: Why not implement the pre-warp yourself? Replace fs with pi*fp/fs

Comment: I don't think it exists.  I was looking for it, too.  If you write it, will you post the code online?

Comment: Doing the pre-warp myself is not a problem, that's true. However, I would prefer the impulse invariance technique, because I experienced much smaller discretization error for my applications.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Python translation of the [Octave impinvar function](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/impinvar.html) in the [PyDynamic package](https://github.com/PTB-PSt1/PyDynamic/blob/master/PyDynamic/misc/impinvar.py) which should be equivalent to the Matlab version.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer! I should have done this long time ago myself. The implementation you've mentioned was done by myself - the PyDynamic package is maintained by me.

Answer (score -1):

Dont have enough rep to comment but new PyDynamic package for new readers is here:
https://github.com/PTB-M4D/PyDynamic/blob/main/src/PyDynamic/misc/impinvar.py

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.